# Getting a public IP for your computer or network

Tags: ip

I need to assign a public IP to my computer to access a CMS on a certain website.
e.g http://www.example.com/wp-admin, a wordpress website has blocked access to their CMS and they will only allow a certain IP address.

Now for temporary usage I go to https://www.whatismyip.com/ and it shows me my IP address, which I provide them and they give me access. But this IP is changing, so I often tell them this is my IP and they give me access using that IP and remove the other one. But I now want to get an IP that won't change?

So the Question is, Can I get a public IP that I can assign to my computer, and they it never changes ?

Comment: This is something you ask your internet service provider.  We can't change how you connect to the internet.

Comment: Contact your ISP about arranging a static (fixed) IP. They usually charge a monthly fee for doing so.  If that's not possible, register your own domain and contract with a hosting service to provide you with one. This site is for programming related questions, and getting an IP address is not a programming question.

Comment: I cannot move or delete this question, can someone please move it to https://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service as no-ip to "convert" your IP to a domain name like mycms.servegame.com, "servegame.com" it's a no-ip domain and the subdomain "mycms" it´s to identified your IP in the DNS.
No-ip service use a software that you can download in your PC, create an account, login and it´s all.
Or in some ISP modems you can configure your no-ip login information to redirect all your subdomain traffic to your IP.